# Maintaining a concentration spell without concentration?

Tags: dnd-5e, concentration

How many ways are there to cast and maintain a concentration spell without anyone having to concentrate on it?  I've seen one -- casting it using a Glyph of Warding.  Are there any others?

Comment: Thinking about it, I'm voting to close as too broad - there are lots of different ways of maintaining a spell without concentration, and which ones work for you will depend on what resources you have, what spell you want to maintain, what kind of spellcaster you are, and so on.

Comment: There are "lots of different ways", such as what?  I don't see what those are, which is why I asked the question.

Comment: For example, having someone else maintain the spell for you. But if the spell you want to maintain is a Target:Self spell, and you want to have it affect you, this doesn't work.

Comment: Alternatively, as the answer below demonstrates, there are methods of maintaining a specific spell. As is, any of those would be a valid answer.

Comment: Having someone else maintain the spell for you isn't maintaining the spell without concentration -- so that's not an answer to the question.  I'll clarify a little.

The example below is a valid, albeit narrow, answer.  This does not look to me at all like "lots of different ways" or "too broad".

Comment: I rescinded my close vote because DMG 263 explicitly warns against creating ways to bypass the concentration mechanic, which seems to limit the potential questions a lot.

Comment: All the solutions presented so far are having to guess which spell(s) you want to avoid concentrating on, making it uncertain which if any are actually relevant solutions. I feel comfortable casting the 5th vote to hold, with the thought that this question should say which spell you're after.

Comment: I didn't specify a particular spell, as I was not after a specific spell solution.  I wanted to find out methods in the game for maintaining concentration spells without concentration, that I could creatively apply to spells as appropriate.  The Glyph of Warding is a good example -- it doesn't specify what spells last their full duration without concentration; it applies to any spells eligible to be cast by the Glyph.

Comment: The potions suggestion in the answer below is closer to what I'm looking for; it has several options, and suggests the idea that other potions might be able to be developed for other spell effects.

Comment: See, that's why it's on hold. If you can tell that one answer is closer to what you're looking for than another but we can't (how is it closer? to what?), there is information missing from the question that's necessary for voters to evaluate the answers. Being more specific in the question would help a lot.

Comment: I can tell that one answer is closer to what I'm looking for, because it addresses the question.  It's not a question about a specific spell, it's a specific question about mechanics in the system for maintaining concentration spells without anyone concentrating.

I don't need you to be able to tell which answers are closest to what I'm looking for, I can read them and decide for myself.  And I DID explain "how is it closer? to what?".

Answer (score 2):

Beyond the example in your question, I could only find a small handful of cases where you get a concentration spell without anybody concentrating on it.

- Guards and Wards: As @Protonflux stated, Guards and Wards allows you to have Suggestions and Stinking Clouds without having to concentrate on them.
- Blackrazor: Technically the item is concentrating for you, but anyway (DMG 217):

  > Blackrazor can cast the haste spell on you once per day. It decides when to cast the spell and maintains concentration on it so that you don't have to.
- Potions: various potions in the DMG (187-188) grant you the effects of spells without any concentration required by anyone. You can get the spells Haste, Bless, Enlarge/Reduce, and Gaseous Form this way. For example, the potion of speed states:

  > When you drink this potion, you gain the effect of the haste spell for 1 minute (no concentration required).

Answer (score 0):

Guards and Wards (phb p.248) allows the caster to place a "*suggestion* in one location" clearly meaning the effects of a suggestion spell. It does not specify the duration or that concentration is required but again clearly it cannot be or the effect would be worthless as the caster cannot possibly be expected to provide such on demand as the effect is triggered. So the only reasonable assumption is that it lasts for the full length of the spell with no concentration requirement as per the Glyph of Warding spell.